# /home/user directory permissions being set to 777

Tags: arch-linux, permissions

Arch up to date with 6.2.2-arch1-1 and git version 2.39.2

On this machine I keep a remote git repo to share with my LAN.

After an update yesterday (300 packages upgraded) I suddenly started getting a password prompt when pulling to projects with working copies on this machine.

Looking about I saw that the user's home directory permission set was 777. This happened before. I fixed it by setting permissions back to 700.

Where can I look to diagnose this? What are the likely/possible causes? Nothing in the upgrade list leaps out.

Answer (score 1):

> What are the likely/possible causes?

- The owner of the home directory has permission to `chmod 777` that folder (which is theirs) as well as `root` being able to do so.
- The owner of the user account can `chmod 777` their home account folder whenever they want, any and every time after you have set it back to `700`.

> Where can I look to diagnose this?

in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` but it will only have a record of such a change if your `/etc/audit/audit.rules` files has the instruction to log `chmod` commands.  That would be something like

```
-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S chmod -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k CHMOD_IDENTIFIER
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S chmod -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k CHMOD_IDENTIFIER
```

You can remove the `-F auid>=1000` in order to capture every chmod including by any account with uid less than 1000 (i.e. root as well).

And you would need auditing enabled obviously: `systemctl enable auditd`

Comment: So is it possible that an update running as root could make such a change?

Comment: **possible** - sure if your update was malware doing something not cool.  But generally speaking no, a valid "update" would not be `chmod 777`'ing one specific user account, does not make sense.  Maybe if it were some obscure installed software written by someone who is not knowledgeable about programming and following convention and installs their stuff under someone's home directory and their update executes a `chmod 777` on its install location or something of that effect, but i'm really reaching and speculating.

Comment: It's for sure *I* didn't do it. Leave it as a a mystery, I guess. Thanks.